# The idea of trade miracle for knowledge

Tags: reference-request

I've read a long time ago the philosophy text that describes the nice and interesting idea that humanity is losing the feeling of the things in nature when they get scientific and precise knowledge about them. In other words, trade miracle for knowledge.

Could you help me find out the name of this direction of philosophical thought?

Comment: This sounds like a critique of society as over rationalized and technocratic. The so called Frankfurt School wrote pieces in this respect. You might consider reading "Dialectic of Enlightenment" by Horkheimer and Adorno.

Comment: Not exactly, I suppose. It's more about the feeling of the world. For example, for  a north medieval man the rainbow was the bridge to Asgard, for modern man it's just ordinary meteorological phenomenon.

Comment: Sounds like McDowell's [disenchantment of nature](https://ojs.grinnell.edu/index.php/gcurj/article/view/430/346).

Comment: Hello and thanks again, Conifold! This term `disenchantment of nature` looks like pretty exact. I'm going to search another works about it. However, it's pretty complicated task, because this process is considering as positive by many philosophers (starting with Weber).

Comment: See also [Disenchantment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disenchantment): "The term was borrowed from Friedrich Schiller by Max Weber to describe the character of modernized, bureaucratic, secularized Western society, where scientific understanding is more highly valued than belief, and where processes are oriented toward rational goals, as opposed to traditional society, where for Weber, "the world remains a great enchanted garden [*The Sociology of Religion* (1920-21)]."